# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition intellisense increasingly slower

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015 Community Edition for several ASP.Net MVC projects.
The editor was nice and fast and I could be very productive. But over a week or two the editor has started "pausing" more and more, not letting me type or do much of anything. Eventually it comes back and types some of what was in the buffer. 
This has gotten worse and worse with time. To the point where it's almost unusable. I have disabled all of the extensions and tools that I have installed but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Eventually I ran VS via `Devenv.exe /resetskippkgs` and everything started running faster again for a week or so then it gradually got worse.

Anyone have any ideas what it might be? I am not running Resharper but am running CodeMaid and Code Digger along with a few MS Powertools.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue doesn't sound typical; what variables can we eliminate?
Extensions are a common culprit.  Try the following:

- Open the Developer Command Prompt (search for Developer)
- Enter: devenv /safemode
- Run in SafeMode for some time and see if the problem is eliminated.

VS ships with a number of built-in, required extensions as well as supporting third party extensions, and it's hard to identify which is which.  SafeMode shuts off only the third-party extensions so your VS continues to operate normally.

If you do not experience the issue running in SafeMode, then try identifying the extension (or combination of extensions) at fault by elimination.

Another possible external cause of symptoms like this could be hardware failure; running a disk analyzer might be in order.

It's entirely possible you've encountered a VS bug, but I don't know of one in 2015 RTM with this profile.  If you use Send-a-Frown (happy face in the upper right margin) when the UI is lagging, a Perf Watson report may be generated automatically.  This would be a big help in trouble-shooting the problem.

Comment: Running in Safemode I still get long delays. Oddly backspace and del will not work but all character keys work.